# cabinet hinges, crooked,uneven some will not close cabinet doors

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, hinges

I recently removed all cabinets to redo them. I had old brass or copper looking hinges. I wanted to change to nickel to match the rest of my kitchen.I have returned 4 different types of hinges because they cause bad overlap.the hinges I now have are made by same company as old ones they are 3/8 inset non self closing. Still having issues. I only have 2 sets hung on both right door is higher than left and on 1 pair doors have to close at same time otherwise there is an overlap.trying to use same shape and size to cover the black stain left by old hinges. I really do not want to cut doors. Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Pictures of old and new hinges would help as would how the doors set. It sounds like you need a larger setback on the new hinges. It is typically called overlay. If the hinge is a face frame mount, move it over a bit, drill new holes. that should keep the doors from overlapping themselves. Again, this depends on the type of hinges you have, and the need for the pictures.

Comment: How do I add pictures to site?

Comment: Typically it is added when the post is created. I think, if I heard right, that new members can't edit their own posts. But it is done by clicking on edit under the post and clicking the picture button and upload the pictures you save of the cabinets on the computer. Or something like that. Other members may know much better than I.

Comment: Cannot get pictures on here. I am getting estimates to have them rehung. I think we may be able to move hinges slightly but my husband refuses to do so, afraid of turning wood into mush from continuing to hang and remove. Hinges are the closest to originals that I could find. I have 7 sets of double doors and 5 single doors. What kind of charge should I be expecting. 2 estimates so far very different in price.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who may be struggling with this issue, there I a simple solution. My cabinets are partial inset, using plain 3/8's inset hinges that were close to my originals in order to cover black markings left on my stiles. I added toothpicks and glue to original holes.so that my screws fit well. But after installed had to close double doors together or they would overlap just a little. I was over my head I couldn't figure out how to fix. I started getting estimates to repair. 100.00 to mill down one side of cabinets. 300.00 to rehang and move hinges over slightly. My last estimate was from Mr. Fix it. He tried to tell me how on the phone. Close the doors together on a paint stick. I had already done this, to hold my gap while installing. He came out with a 5 gallon paint stick. 1/4 inch thick. He closed the doors together,gently, on the stick twice and my problem was gone. He called it setting the hinges. I couldn't believe that's all it took. Wanted to share with anyone having similar issue. So that they wouldn't have sleepless nights and wasted tears, and messed up cabinets.